# Efficient function for creating JSON data from File Directory Structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, jstree

Like the title says, I have a directory structure, I want to convert it into a JSON format compatible for [jsTree usage](http://www.jstree.com/docs/json/).
So the output for a given list

**INPUT:**

```
./Simple Root Node
./Root Node 2
./Root Node 2/Child 1
./Root Node 2/Child 2
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
treeJSON = [
       { "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Simple root node" },
       { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node 2" },
       { "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 1" },
       { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2" },
    ]
```

**My Method:**

Currently, I'm taking each line from the input. Say `./Root Node 2/Child 1`, then I pattern match the first folder, creating an array like `{ "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node 2" }`. Then go recursively for the next removing the first folder.Hence, creating the net array as `{ "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2" }`.

I do this for each line in the input and then use my unique array function as in http://jsfiddle.net/bsw5s60j/8/ to strip all the duplicate arrays which were created. For instance, `{ "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node 2" }` would be created twice. Once while going through the 3rd line and then the 4th line.

Clearly, this code is HIGHLY inefficient.If I have around 1.3K directories, then assume each has 4 sub directories, we have 5.2K arrays which have to be checked for duplicates.

This is creating a hge problem. Is there any other efficient way I can twaek this code?

**Fiddle: (Works with Chrome Only because of the file webkit attribute)**  http://jsfiddle.net/bsw5s60j/8/

**Javascript**

```
 var input = document.getElementById('files');
 var narr = [];
 var fileICON = "file.png";

 //when browse button is pressed
 input.onchange = function (e) {
     var dummyObj = [];
     var files = e.target.files; // FileList
     for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; ++i) {
         var fname = './' + files[i].webkitRelativePath;
         narr = $.merge(dummyObj, (cat(fname)));
     }

     treeJSON = narr.getUnique(); // getting the JSON tree after processing input
     console.log(JSON.stringify(treeJSON));

     //creating the tree using jstree

     $('#tree')
         .jstree({
         'core': {
             'check_callback': true,
                 'data': function (node, cb) {
                 cb.call(this, treeJSON);
             }
         }
     });
     var tree = $('#tree').jstree(true);
     tree.refresh();
 };

 //get unqiue array function
 Array.prototype.getUnique = function () {
     var o = {}, a = [];
     for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i) {
         if (o.hasOwnProperty(JSON.stringify(this[i]))) {
             continue;
         }
         a.push(this[i]);
         o[JSON.stringify(this[i])] = 1;
     }
     return a;
 };

 // categorizing function which converts each ./Files/Root/File.jpg to a JSON

 var objArr = [];
 var folderArr = [];

 function cat(a) {
     if (!a.match(/\/(.+?)\//)) {
         var dummyObj = {};
         var fname = a.match(/\/(.*)/)[1];
         dummyObj.id = fname;
         dummyObj.text = fname;
         if (folderArr === undefined || folderArr.length == 0) {
             dummyObj.parent = '#';
         } else {
             dummyObj.parent = folderArr[(folderArr.length) - 1];
             dummyObj.icon = fileICON; // add extention and icon support
         }
         objArr.push(dummyObj);
         return objArr;
     } else {
         if (a.charAt(0) == '.') {
             var dummyObj = {};
             var dir1 = a.match(/^.*?\/(.*?)\//)[1];
             dummyObj.id = dir1;
             dummyObj.text = dir1;
             dummyObj.parent = '#';
             dummyObj.state = {
                 'opened': true,
                     'selected': true
             }; // not working
             folderArr.push(dir1);
             objArr.push(dummyObj);
             var remStr = a.replace(/^[^\/]*\/[^\/]+/, '');
             cat(remStr);
             return objArr;
         } else {
             var dummyObj = {};
             var dir1 = a.match(/^.*?\/(.*?)\//)[1];
             dummyObj.id = dir1;
             dummyObj.text = dir1;
             dummyObj.parent = folderArr[(folderArr.length) - 1];
             folderArr.push(dir1);
             objArr.push(dummyObj);
             var remStr = a.replace(/^[^\/]*\/[^\/]+/, '');
             cat(remStr);
             return objArr;
         }
     }
 }
```

**HTML**

```
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple webkitdirectory />
<div id="tree"></div>
```

Any changes or suggestions would be greatly helpful! Thanks

Comment: Please post your code in the question.

Comment: Does the input data need to be validated? Is it sorted, like in your example?

Comment: @Bergi I've added as the coded as requested.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle and code.Now you can clearly see what the function does.

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep Where does the list of files/directories come from? Ideally you should generate the JSON directly there (i.e. on the server) instead of generating a huge list in the first place.

Comment: @mb21 The exact code is given in the fiddle.The input is given via a 'browse' button. Typically, I would expect around 1.3k files to be selected. You mean I should process the data server side and not client side?

Comment: Whatever you do, this will work only in Chrome, `webkitdirectory` or just `directory` is still not a web standard. This also means the question is Chrome-specific and you should add Chrome tag to it.

Comment: @skobaljic Yes, I know that. I've an else case for other browsers. That isn't the problem just in case you're wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple algorithm that should do quite efficiently, using a map from filepaths to their ids:

```
var idcount = 0;
var treeJSON = [];
var idmap = {};
function add(dirs) {
    if (!dirs.length) return "#";
    var name = dirs.join("/");
    if (name in idmap)
        return idmap[name];
    var dir = dirs.pop();
    var parent = add(dirs);
    var id = "ajson" + ++idcount;
    treeJSON.push({id: id, parent: parent, text: dir});
    return idmap[name] = id;
}

var files = e.target.files; // FileList
for (var i=0; i<files.length; ++i) {
    var name = files[i].webkitRelativePath;
    add(name.split("/"));
}
return treeJSON;
```

([updated jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bsw5s60j/9/))

This is how you might use it for dynamic updates:

```
// initalise JStree here

var idcount = 0;
var treeJSON = [];
var idmap = {};
function add(dirs, isfolder) {
    if (!dirs.length) return "#";
    var name = dirs.join("/");
    if (name in idmap) {
        if (isfolder && idmap[name].icon)
            delete idmap[name].icon;
        return idmap[name];
    }
    var dir = dirs.pop();
    var parent = add(dirs, true);
    var id = "ajson" + ++idcount;
    var item = {id: id, parent: parent, text: dir}

    if (parent == "#")
        item.state = {opened:true, selected:true};
    if (!isfolder && dir.indexOf(".") > 0)
        item.icon = fileICON;

    treeJSON.push(item);
    return idmap[name] = id;
}

input.onchange = function(e) {
    var files = e.target.files; // FileList
    for (var i=0; i<files.length; ++i) {
        var name = files[i].webkitRelativePath;
        add(name.split("/"), false);
    }
    // refresh JStree
};
```

Comment: Files become folders in [this script](http://jsfiddle.net/bsw5s60j/10/). Think files should be ignored.

Comment: @skobaljic I think that is a minor error.I'm looking into it too. You're function seems to be nice. I will accept if it if there is no other good solution is there. I'm still looking into the code

Comment: I also think it is a minor issue, but [Bergi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) should fix it.

Comment: @skobaljic: Can you tell me how the `treeJSON` should look differently? As I don't use Chrome, it would be nice if you could make a demo with a fake `files` array.

Comment: @Bergi I'e given the fake files array with 2 files. I want to set a different icon to them. http://jsfiddle.net/bsw5s60j/11/ 

I'm just wondering, isn't yours more efficient than Ivan's solution?

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep: So you expect an `.icon` property set on your `treeJSON` objects whose name contains a dot? Or how would I distinguish files from folders?

Comment: My solution is pretty similar to @IvanSivak's one, except he seems to depend on the order of the input array (folders must appear before all contents of them).

Comment: In my Chrome I do not get folders at all, only files, such as: `iOS/2_iPhone_Splashscreens/._1242x2208.png`, `iOS/3_iPad_Splashscreens/._768x1024.png`, speaking for list he gets with `var files = e.target.files;`

Comment: @Bergi Also, I've found another problem. I've updated the code here : When I try to upload another file list, it seems to give me a problem. It doesnt append the new JSON tree to the old one. Also, it seems to seems to overlap with ID's the second time to upload. http://jsfiddle.net/bsw5s60j/12/

Comment: @Bergi Rather than a dot, it should be the last element in the subdirectory and a dot. If not it would be a problem when a folder with a dote is scanned. PS: Rearding the icon, it could be at the same level as the first folder you encounter.

Comment: I wll have a look at it in around 10 hours and give the bounty! Thanks for your time

Comment: Hey, I have a small doubt. I want to add this item in the object `"state: {
           'opened' : true,
           'selected' : true
         },"` when the parent is `'#'`. How do i do that? I would write a clumsy if.. else function but I would like to get a shorthand version of yours. Also, I would like to have different icons for different extensions, say `'.avi'` and `'.srt'` will have different icons. Thank you!

Comment: I think an `if (parent == "#")` statement is totally fine here, complementing the existing feature for detection of files. Same for extensions, just check them and set `.icon` accordingly.

Comment: I fixed that. I seemed to have run into another problem. When the browser is chrome, the input selection of files is different. 'isFolder' doesnt work. Any modifications that will let me use this on ff too?

Comment: Make sure to pass an array of filepath parts, the last of which should contain a dot. Browser differences should only need to be handled in the `onchange` function, `add` is generic.